# (Amd GPU) Error in DP aux read transaction , not writing source specific data

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, touchpad, hp-pavilion

I switched from Manjaro Plasma to Kubuntu last night to see if my trackpad works there... It doesn't... But now it won't turn on. After turning the laptop on it keeps saying
(Amd GPU) Error in DP aux read transaction , not writing source specific data
I am quite new to linux... And have been switching distros to see if the trackpad works on any... On Kubuntu it worked on the live usb once but after a reboot it stopped working and after installation this error showed up

Please help!

The laptop is HP Pavilion Gaming 15EC
The touchpad is Elantech
It has a dedicated NvidiaGPU
And an integrated AMD GPU